# Тире в зависимости от смысла

Tags: тире

Скажите, ставится ли тире в предложении:

> Эта работа Комарова - напоминание людям.

Comment: @more, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Эта работа Комарова -- напоминание
> людям...

Тире в этом предложении необходимо.

**P.S.**

Надеюсь на то, что предложение словом "людям" не заканчивается. Необходимо продолжение:

*напоминание людям **[о чём-то, о ком-то...]***